# how can use php dotnet class in linux - php v 7.x

Tags: php, asp.net, linux

I want to use dll files in PHP.  I tried:

```
$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
$stack->Push(".Net");
$stack->Push("Hello ");
echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
```

I get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOTNET' not found in
>   /home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/index.php on
>   line 3

I  changed my php.ini file that has this error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll' (tried:
>   /home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll
>   (/home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll: invalid ELF header),
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll.so
>   (/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
>   on line 0 
>  **Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library '/home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll' (tried:
>   /home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll
>   (/home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll: invalid ELF header),
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll.so
>   (/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//home/hafs/Desktop/wine/mscorlib.dll/myApp.dll.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in
>   **Unknown** on line **0**
>   PHP 7.2.7 Development Server started at Mon Oct 15 22:44:22 2018
>
> ---

What can I do?

Comment: You can't do that. DLL files are for Windows.

Comment: Dotnet class in php.net  just for win?

Comment: this can happen in windows host i try it :-)